# Android custom url scheme opening new browser tab along with native app

Tags: java, javascript, android

We have an app that handles a custom URL scheme in Android device. In case the app is not installed in the device the request from web page should redirect to an information page (having link to the google play market). When ever we try to launch the app from web page, it launches in our app and opens the information on browser window which is not an expected behavior. We need to launch the app without opening another browser tab.I tried using webkitHidden property as suggested in one of your forum.But it fixes the problem for Chrome browser.I would really appreciate if you can suggest a solution to handle this in other browsers too, like internet browser (found in Samsung Galaxy Tab) and Firefox.